# Heroku Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I'm trying to push my application to Heroku, but I'm running into some issues:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'
>   2019-04-10T01:38:23.050188+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL6WB.png)     at
>   Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3) 2019-04-10T01:38:23.050190+00:00
>   app[web.1]: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL6WB.png)     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
>   2019-04-10T01:38:23.050192+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL6WB.png)     at
>   Object. (/app/config/database.js:4:39)

It seems that the error is the variable `envConfig`, but i need it for database to work.

As of now, I'm getting

[image]

Here is my `config/database.js`:

```
if (!process.env.PG_DB) {
    const fs = require('fs')
    const dotenv = require('dotenv')
    // dotenv, but i need this make the database work
    const envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync('.env'))

    for (var k in envConfig) {
      process.env[k] = envConfig[k]
    }

    console.log('[api][sequelize] Loaded database ENV vars from .env file')
  }

  module.exports = {
    development: {
      username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
      dialect: 'postgres',
      migrationStorageTableName: 'sequelize_meta'
    },

    production: {
      username: "root",
      password: null,
      database: "*********some postgress url",
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      dialect: "postgres"
    }
```

And my `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var userRoute = require('./routes/users');
var postRoute  = require('./routes/posts');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser') ;
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var env = dotenv.config();
var cors = require('cors');
var models = require('./models/');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
// const allowOrigin = process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN || '*'
// CORS Middleware
if (!process.env.PORT) {
  require('dotenv').config()
}
if (!process.env.PORT) {
  console.log('[api][port] 8000 set as default')
  console.log('[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * set as default')
} else {
  console.log('[api][node] Loaded ENV vars from .env file')
  console.log(`[api][port] ${process.env.PORT}`)
  console.log(`[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ${process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN}`)
}
require('./config/passport-github');
require('./config/passport');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret : process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 84,
  resave: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false})); 
const isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    next();
    console.log('this works');
  }else{
   res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8001/signIn');
  }
}
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
//   // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',  true);
//   res.header("preflightContinue", false)
//   // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
//   next();
// });
app.use(cors({
    'allowedHeaders': ['Content-Type'], // headers that React is sending to the API
    'exposedHeaders': ['Content-Type'], // headers that you are sending back to React
    'origin': '*',
    'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    'preflightContinue': false
}));
app.use('/api/users', userRoute );
app.use('/api/posts', isAuthenticated,  postRoute );
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user; // This is the important line
  // req.session.user = user
  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});
models.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${port}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever
compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you do anything else, if those are your real credentials you should invalidate them ***immediately***. They are forever
compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is ***not enough***.

---

You can change

```
const envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync('.env'))
```

to

```
const envConfig = dotenv.config({silent: true})
```

You don't need to manually read the file here, and skipping it lets you gracefully handle the case when it doesn't exist. There's also no need to manually set values in `process.env`:

```
for (var k in envConfig) {
  process.env[k] = envConfig[k]
}
```

This can be entirely skipped. Dotenv takes care of this itself. Therefore, you don't need `envConfig` either, reducing all of that to just

```
dotenv.config({silent: true})
```

If `.env` exists, its contents will be added to what's already in `process.env`. In development, this gives you a convenient way to set your database connection information.

In production, `.env` shouldn't exist, and your database connection information *definitely* shouldn't be hard-coded. Instead, your database connection information should come from one or more [Heroku config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) (these are environment variables that should already be available via `process.env`). Your database addon has probably already set the `DATABASE_URL` variable for you.

For things in your `.env` that you've set yourself, set a Heroku config var for its production value. You can do that through the Heroku web dashboard or via the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli):

```
heroku config:set SOME_VARIABLE=foo
```